# .gitattributes not setting attr 'text eol' properly

Tags: git, gitattributes, git-ls-files

Sample from `.gitattributes` file that was recently committed.

```
* text=auto eol=lf
*.bat text eol=crlf
*.cmd text eol=crlf
*.ahk text eol=crlf
*.ps1 text eol=lf
```

Current output of `git ls-files --eol` below. Note that file `a.ps1` is currently a newly created staged file and file `b.ps1` was added in a previous commit when `*.ps1 text eol=crlf` existed in the `.gitattributes` file.

```
i/lf    w/lf    attr/text eol=crlf      a.ps1
i/lf    w/crlf  attr/text eol=crlf      b.ps1
```

Expected output of `git ls-files --eol` below

```
i/lf    w/lf  attr/text eol=lf      a.ps1
i/lf    w/lf  attr/text eol=lf      b.ps1
```

I can correct the `w/` line ending to `lf` by just manually changing the local files, but why does it not say `attr/text eol=lf`?

Does someone happen to know what is happening? OS is windows, if that matters. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution, although at this time I am not sure what really happened.

I use git submodules. Top level git repo A had submodule B; B is the repo mentioned in this question. There was a file `A/.git/modules/B/info/attributes` that was an older version of my `B/.gitattributes` file. Deleting this old file allowed `B/.gitattributes` to be utilized and for `attr/text eol=lf` to be set appropriately for `a.ps1` and `b.ps1`.

Comment: The `info/attributes` settings will override the `.gitattributes` settings in the case of any conflict, so that's probably the full explanation.